Proper method for swapping radius arm bushings on 1992-2014 Ford Van
I am thinking about swapping out the radius arm bushings on a 1998 Ford Van.
Most tutorials and videos on this job show people removing the bracket from the frame rail, but...
This this video at timestamp 19:39, the gentleman pushes the front hub forwards somehow such that the radius arm comes all the way out of the bracket.
This would be really nice because the bracket is a major PITA.  But I'm worried about bending or snapping something.  Is the front end built to be moved in this way?
